# for..each loop for Adobe air form controls

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have four TextInput controls in a adobe air form.
They are showing in a panel named : pnlUnlockCode.

Now what I want to do is to implement a for..each loop for these four TextInput like

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    c.Height = this.Height * (sizes[count].Height / SCALE_H);
    c.Width = this.Width * (sizes[count].Width / SCALE_W);
    c.Left = this.Width * (positions[count].X / SCALE_W);
    c.Top = this.Height * (positions[count].Y / SCALE_H);
}
```

in c#.

Please pull me from this problem.

Awaiting your response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
for( var i:int=0; i < pnlUnlockCode.numElements; i++){
   var c:TextInput in pnlUnlockCode.getElementAt(i)
   ...
}
```

Comment: 'getChildren' does not exists for pnlUnlockCode. 

Getting 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildren through a reference with static type spark.components:Panel.

Comment: Yo `getChildren()` is not a display object container method. Use `numChildren` and `getChildAt` instead.

Comment: For spark container, getChildAt does not exist anymore. Updated sample code to use getElementAt instead

Comment: Oha! how they can prevent `getChildAt` from being used in a subclass of DisplayObjectContainer?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try:

```
var numControls : uint = pnlUnlockCode.numChildren;
for (var i : uint; i < numControls; i++) {
    var control : TextInput = pnlUnlockCode.getChildAt(i) as TextInput;
    control.setActualSize(sizes[count].Width / SCALE_W, sizes[count].Height / SCALE_H);
    control.move(positions[count].X / SCALE_W, positions[count].Y / SCALE_H);
}
```

Note, you can apply scalings also by setting the `scaleX, scaleY` properties of a display object.

And here another note:

`setActualSize(w, h)` sets the size apparently not reliably. I cound not find any Flex method to set `widht` and `height` in one run. So you perhaps will be better to use the width and height properties individually:

```
control.width = ...;
control.height = ...;
```

Could someone confirm this?

Comment: I guess the best way is to set them individually. setActualSize seems to have other purpose.

Comment: Flex calculates the size of a component in a rather compliated "layout pass" considering percentage, default, min or max values and layout rules. The result of this pass is the actual size. You can set this on your own, but if you do so, Flex will reset (recalculate) this in the next layout pass.